# How to report the error message in proper order

Tags: bison

I want to implement an expression validation tool with Flex&Bison. In my tool, I accept an expression  terminated with ';' and check if there are something wrong inside the expression. When error occures, I want to get the proper positon of the error token. The question is, when there are more than one error occurred, I always get wrong position.

parser:

```
%{
#  include <stdio.h>
#  include <stdlib.h>
#  include "roofexp.h"
#  include "symbol.h"
%}

%locations

%union {
  struct ast *a;
  double d;
  struct symbol *s;     /* which symbol */
  struct symlist *sl;
  int fn;           /* which function */
  char *str;
}

/* edeclare tokens */
%token <d> NUMBER
%token <str> STRING
%token <s> NAME
%token <fn> FUNC
%token EOL

%token IF THEN ELSE WHILE DO LET


%nonassoc <fn> CMP
%right '='
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%nonassoc '|' UMINUS

%type <a> exp stmt list explist

%start calclist

%%
calclist: /* nothing */
    | calclist stmt ';' {
                            if(debug) 
                                dumpast($2, 0);
                             printf("= %4.4g\n> ", eval($2));
                             treefree($2);
                             free_string_table();
                             FreeSymbolTable();
                        }
    | calclist error EOL { YYERROR; }
 ;

stmt: IF exp THEN list           { $$ = newflow('I', $2, $4, NULL); }
   | IF exp THEN list ELSE list  { $$ = newflow('I', $2, $4, $6); }
   | exp
;

list: /* nothing */ { $$ = NULL; }
   | stmt ';' list { if ($3 == NULL)
                    $$ = $1;
                      else
            $$ = newast('L', $1, $3);
                    }
   ;

exp: exp CMP exp          { $$ = newcmp($2, $1, $3); }
   | exp '+' exp          { $$ = newast('+', $1,$3); }
   | exp '-' exp          { $$ = newast('-', $1,$3);}
   | exp '*' exp          { $$ = newast('*', $1,$3); }
   | exp '/' exp          { 
                                $$ = newast('/', $1, $3);
                          }
   | '|' exp              { $$ = newast('|', $2, NULL); }
   | '(' exp ')'          { $$ = $2; }
   | '-' exp %prec UMINUS { $$ = newast('M', $2, NULL); }
   | NUMBER               { $$ = newnum($1); }
   | STRING               { $$ = newstr($1); add_string($1); } 
   | FUNC '(' explist ')' { $$ = newfunc($1, $3); }
   | NAME                 { $$ = newref($1); }
   | NAME '=' exp         { $$ = newasgn($1, $3); }
   | NAME '(' explist ')' { $$ = newcall($1, $3); }
;

explist: exp                  
        | exp ',' explist  { $$ = newast('L', $1, $3); }
;
```

lexer:

```
%%
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
# include "roofexp.h"
# include "roofexp.tab.h"
# include "symbol.h"

/* handle locations */
int yycolumn = 1;
#define YY_USER_ACTION \
    yylloc.first_line = yylloc.last_line = yylineno;    \
    yylloc.first_column = yycolumn; \
    yylloc.last_column = yycolumn + yyleng - 1; \
    yycolumn += yyleng;
%}

%option yylineno noyywrap
/* float exponent */
EXP ([Ee][-+]?[0-9]+)

%%
 /* single character ops */
"#" |
"+" |
"-" |
"*" |
"/" |
"=" |
"|" |
"," |
";" |
"(" |
")"     { return yytext[0]; }

 /* comparison ops */
">"     { yylval.fn = 1; return CMP; }
"<"     { yylval.fn = 2; return CMP; }
"<>"    { yylval.fn = 3; return CMP; }
"=="    { yylval.fn = 4; return CMP; }
">="    { yylval.fn = 5; return CMP; }
"<="    { yylval.fn = 6; return CMP; }

 /* keywords */

"if"    { return IF; }
"then"  { return THEN; }
"else"  { return ELSE; }
"while" { return WHILE; }
"do"    { return DO; }
"let"   { return LET;}

 /* built in functions */
"sin"   { yylval.fn = FUNC_sin; return FUNC; }
"cos"   { yylval.fn = FUNC_cos; return FUNC; }
"pow" { yylval.fn = FUNC_pow; return FUNC; }
"GetDz" { yylval.fn = FUNC_GetDz; return FUNC;}

 /* debug hack */
"debug"[0-9]+ { debug = atoi(&yytext[5]); printf("debug set to %d\n", debug); }

 /* names */
[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*  { 
                        if(LookupSymbolTable(yytext, 0, VARIABLE) == NULL)
                            yyerror("未定义的变量: %s", yytext);
                        else
                            yylval.s = lookup(yytext); return NAME; 
                        }

[0-9]+"."[0-9]*{EXP}? |
"."?[0-9]+{EXP}? { yylval.d = atof(yytext); return NUMBER; }

\"[^\"\n]*\"    { printf("string=%s\n", yytext); }
\"[^\"\n]*$     { yyerror("unterminated string literal: %s\n", yytext); }

"//".*  
[ \t]   
\n      { yycolumn = 1;  }
.       { yyerror("Mystery character %c\n", *yytext); }
%%
```

Expression:

```
pow(2)+
pow(2, 4)
;
```

Echo:

```
3-1: error: at ';': too few arguments for call
```

But the right position should be 1-1! 
What's wrong with my lexer and parser. And if I want to get the proper position, how shoule I do?

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you showed the code which generates the error message, but my guess is that your `yyerror` function just uses the current value of `yyloc`, which will correspond to the last token read. Consequently, if errors (like "too few arguments") are not diagnosed until the semicolon at the end of the expression, then `yyloc` will have the location of the semicolon, as seen in your example.

When you specify `%locations` to bison, then bison keeps a source range for every non-terminal, as well as the non-terminals. (By default, the range runs from the start of the first component in the production to the end of the last one.) You can access the location struct from a bison action using `@N` (for component `N`) or `@$` (for the entire range of the reduction).

However, using `@$` in your `calclist stmt ';'` action (assuming that your error is produced during the call to `eval`) will not give you much more precision. The best that you would be able to do at that point is to report the error as being somewhere in the source code range `1:1-3:1`. In order to produce more accurate messages, you'll need to include the location in each node in the AST. Then `eval` will only have to know which AST node caused the error.

Of course, you could produce errors like `too few arguments` when you parse the function call, assuming you know how many arguments each function requires at that point. But that's harder to maintain and less general.

Although bison does a lot of the work needed to maintain locations, you have to keep the association of location information with AST node yourself. The usual way of doing this is to include a `YYLTYPE` struct in each AST node (your `struct ast`); you can copy the appropriate location into the AST node in the action which creates the node.